# VBA IF/THEN Find & Replace

Tags: vba, excel

I wanted to ask for some help on how to incorporate an if-then statement in my vba code that find's and replaces certain text.

My situation has several sets of numbers: 8815, 0815, 1234 & 5678 and my current code finds "815" and replaces it with '0815 so that the leading zero isn't lost. Ovbiously my issue is the replace statement it executing correctly on the 0815 set of numbers and is executing on the 8815 set of numbers.

How can I write a command to say, if 8815 then 8815 but not to change the number if "815" isn't in the number?

```
 Columns("H").Replace What:="815", Replacement:="'0815", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns
```

I appreciate any help with this as, I've been looking around for a few hours and haven't found too much on this.

Comment: Would it be possible to just format the column as text?

Comment: Couldn't you just format the column as custom `0000` so that it always shows 4 digits with leading 0's if necessary?

Comment: Normally I could, but I'm pulling my data from a webquery which is overwriting any formatting changes that I put on the cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use argument `LookAt:=xlWhole` this will only replace if the value in the cell is exactly the value you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Barry, It should be:

Columns("H:H").Replace What:="815", Replacement:="'0815", LookAt:=xlWhole

or if you want to use IF statement then it should be like this:

```
Sub test()

    Dim rngColumn       As Range
    Dim rngCell         As Range

    Set rngColumn = Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("H")
    For Each rngCell In rngColumn.Cells
        If Trim(rngCell) <> "" Then
            If Trim(rngCell) = "815" Then
                rngCell.Value = "'0815"
            End If
        End If
    Next rngCell

    Set rngColumn = Nothing
    Set rngCell = Nothing

End Sub
```